# Catch ExpatError in xmltodict

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xmltodict

I am using [`xmltodict`](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) to parse xml.

If we parse invalid xml, it throws up an `ExpatError`.

How do I catch this? Here is what I've tried in my ipython shell

```
>>> import xmltodict
>>> xml_data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
...     <Website>"""

>>> xml_dict = xmltodict.parse(xml_data)
ExpatError: no element found

>>> try:                      
...     xml_dict = xmltodict.parse(xml_data)
... except ExpatError:
...     print "that's right"
NameError: name 'ExpatError' is not defined

>>> try:                      
...     xml_dict = xmltodict.parse(xml_data)
... except xmltodict.ExpatError:
...     print "that's right"
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ExpatError'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to import the [`ExpatError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pyexpat.html#xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError) from [`xml.parsers.expact`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pyexpat.html).

```
from xml.parsers.expat import ExpatError
```

Comment: Realized that we can import directly from xmltodict as well. Thanks and +1  for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 8):

Found it, within `xmltodict` module itself, so no need to import it separately from `xml` module

```
>>> try:                                             
...     xml_dict = xmltodict.parse(xml_data)
... except xmltodict.expat.ExpatError:
...     print "that's right"
... 
that's right
```